# set echo ON in Python call to Oracle SQL is not working

Tags: python, subprocess

I am beginner in Python, i am trying to access oracle DB from Python program. I am able to get the output with the below code. However, i want the SQL query which i ran along with the output. I am only getting the output. I tried 'set echo on' but its not working. Please help me.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

##  Imports
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os
import sys

sql1='set echo ON; \n select name from v$database;'
sqlplus = Popen(["sqlplus", "-S", "/", "as", "sysdba"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
sqlplus.stdin.write(sql1);

out, err = sqlplus.communicate()
print out
```

Current Output:

```
=================
Exexution Details:
===========
 ./test_db.py
NAME
---------
testdb
```

I want the SQL query also to be printed along with output as below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed after using SQL file instead of direct commands.

sqlplus = Popen(["sqlplus", "-S", "/", "as", "sysdba", "@file.sql"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)